# NextJS delete currentUser from DB but still logged in

Tags: session, next.js

I delete the current logged in user and I am still able to navigate on my Nextjs app

How to delete session or clear cookies if my user is not my DB anymore ?

Comment: You can try to delete the session and cookie before you delete the user. What kind of authentication are you using (if any). Depending on the type of authentication there are logout functions that exist so you could force log a user out after

Comment: Im using NextAuth for my web app

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty easy to solve now.

With NextAuth you can use the built in signOut function which has a built in callback to force redirect a user on Sign Out.

```
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

const someDeleteUserFunction = () => {
   // delete user code

   signOut({ callbackUrl: "/login" })

}
```

The cookies that get created on login will also get deleted when the user is signed out.

Some other things you can do is. Implement some page authentication using `getServerSideProps` so that way if the user is not authenticated they won't be able to access the pages (but if their cookie still exist, you won't be able to do anything)

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

export async function getServerSideProps(context: any) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/login",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { session },
  };
}
```

There is also another way to implement some middleware to be for specific pages over using `getServerSideProps`

https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes

If none of these methods work. You could install a package like `js-cookies` or `universal-cookies` and forcefully delete the cookies by their names after your deleteUser function and then the `getServerSideProps` would redirect after